# calculate all combinations that add up to a number

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have a script that gives me all possible combinations of a set of numbers adding up to a number. But I do not want a minimum or maximum number, but I want to be able to enter the numbers I need. So my target could be '3' and the set containing the numbers 1 and 2. As you can see I want also be able to have all possible order and each number can be used more than once. The result in this case would be: `1+1+1, 2+1, 1+2`. I also want the number of results to be displayed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sum</title>
</head>

<body>

  <style>
    .table {
      display: table;
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .table-row {
      display: table-row;
    }
    
    .cell {
      display: table-cell;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="cell">Target:</div>
      <div class="cell">
        <input id="target" type="text" value=15>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">n:</div>
      <div class="cell">
        <input id="n" type="text" value=3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="cell">Min:</div>
      <div class="cell">
        <input id="min" type="text" value=1>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">Max:</div>
      <div class="cell">
        <input id="max" type="text" value=12>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="submit" />
  <div id="output" />

  <script>
    function getCombos(target, min, max, n) {
      var arrs = [];
      if (n === 1 && target <= max) {
        arrs.push([target]);
      } else {
        for (var i = min; i < target / n && i <= max; i++) {
          var nextTarget = target - i;
          var nextMin = i + 1;
          var arrays = getCombos(nextTarget, nextMin, max, n - 1);
          for (var j = 0; j < arrays.length; j++) {
            var array = arrays[j];
            array.splice(0, 0, i);
            arrs.push(array);
          }
        }
      }
      return arrs;
    }

    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
      var target = document.getElementById("target").value;
      var min = document.getElementById("min").value;
      var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
      var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
      var result = getCombos(+target, +min, +max, +n);
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result.join("<br/>");
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: BTW, this is the subset-sum problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is a version of the [subset-sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) (but instead of summing to `0`, you are summing to some desired number).

The Wikipedia page does give an `O(2 ^ (n/2))`, however since your inputs seem small, I will just implement the `O(2 ^ N * N)` brute-force algorithm to solve this.

```
function get_summing_subsets(set_arr, target){
     let finish = [];
     let working = [[]];
     while (working.length){
         let next_work = [];
         for (let i = 0; i < working.length; i++){
             for (let j = 0; j < set_arr.length; j++){
                 let subset = working[i].concat([set_arr[j]]);
                 let sum = subset.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
                 if (sum <= target){
                     (sum == target ? finish : next_work).push(subset);
                 }
             }
         }
         working = next_work
     }
     return finish;
}
```

which works well:

```
//your example
get_summing_subsets([1,2], 3)
[[1,2],[2,1],[1,1,1]]
//another
get_summing_subsets([1,2,3], 4)
[[1,3],[2,2],[3,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[2,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
```

Comment: Somehow I can't get it working. Can you show the entire script or URL for me?

Comment: what do you mean? just put that function somewhere in your `<script>` tags and then either `console.log(get_summing_subsets([1,2], 3))` or set the text of some element to that result

Comment: OK, thanks, got it working. 1 question though: how can enter one third. A half is 0.5 and works fine, but 3x0.33 doesn't give 1. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you cant use floats, you will have to either create your own or use a built-in structure to store the numerators and denominators of your fractions and then you can add them accurately (using lcm)

Comment: Is it possible to have always 8 values on each array, the first 5 places to be filled from arr1 and the rest from arr2?

Comment: Of course! You will probably be best to re-write the for-loop over the `j` variable to go over  either `arr1` *or* `arr2` depending on whether the length of `working[i]` is greater than 5 or not.